# OBject access from different functions in VC++

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt, visual-c++

I have 3 function in my class B. These three function have to access member function of other class A.

I did this by creating object of class A in class B constructor and tried to access that object in functions of class B. But its showing error.

How can i assess the same object in these three functions. Where i have to create object of class A

```
B::B()
{ 
  A a;
 }
B:: function()
{
 a.fun(); //fun belongs to class A
}
B:: function1()
{
 a.fun1(); //fun1 belongs to class A
}
```

I am getting error, How can i implement the same where i can access object a in both function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `a` a member variable of class `B` like this:

```
class B
{
private:
    A a;

// ...
}
```

That will make it available to all the member functions of `B`.

(Making it `private` isn't necessary - the decision to make it `private`, `protected` or `public` depends on whether you want to make it available only within `B`, within `B` and `B`'s derived classes, or everywhere.)

Answer (score 3):

You should add A as a member of your B class, and not as a local variable of the B constructor.
Try this:

```
class B
{
public:
  B();
  void function1();

private:
  // This is your member, and you can access it from all of B's methods.
  A m_a;
};
```